# Determine byte order of uint32_t

Tags: c++, linux, vxworks

I am converting a vxWorks application to Linux.

Previously, I had a `union` with a `word` and a `struct` so that when I accessed the members of the `struct`, I could use the `word's` layout to build my `struct` members.

However, I don't recall how I figured this out and it works on the vxWorks box. On my vxWorks instance, the layout is:

```
typedef union Status
{
    struct fields
    {
        uint32_t byteA : 1; // <31>
        uint32_t blank : 23; // <30:8>
        uint32_t bytesN : 8; // <7:0>
    } fields;

    uint32_t word;
}
```

I've already ran into some endian issues while porting from vxWorks to Linux. So figuring out the layout of `uint32_t` on linux is important.

Comment: shouldn't something like this do the trick? 
`uint32_t foobar = 0x00ff00ff;
if (((char *) foobar)[0] == 0xff) /* one endianess */
else /* the other */`

Comment: Are you asking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359629/union-hack-for-endian-testing-and-byte-swapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921933/determine-byte-order-of-uint32-t/7922078#7922078), you want whatever is stuffed into the `word` member of the `union` to appear in the `fields.bytesN` member. To achieve this you must either have some kind of pre-build process that lays out the `field` bit fields appropriately after detecting machine endianness, or create 2 structures, one for big endian and the other for little endian.

```
typedef union Status
{
    struct fieldsBE
    {
        uint32_t byteA : 1; // <31>
        uint32_t blank : 23; // <30:8>
        uint32_t bytesN : 8; // <7:0>
    } fieldsBE;

    struct fieldsLE
    {
        uint32_t bytesN : 8; // <7:0>
        uint32_t blank : 23; // <30:8>
        uint32_t byteA : 1; // <31>
    } fieldsLE;

    uint32_t word;
};

int main()
{
  bool isBigEndian = DetectEndianness(); // returns true if big endian

  Status status;

  status.word = 40;

  if( isBigEndian ) {
    uint8_t bytesN = status.fieldsBE.bytesN;

  } else {
    uint8_t bytesN = status.fieldsLE.bytesN;

  }
}
```

Of course, if you only want to support little endian in your port use the layout of `fieldsLE` instead of the original layout you've shown.

Comment: but I had to change bytesN to 31, blank to 23, and byteA to 1.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell by taking a pointer to an `int` containing the value 0x01 and casting it to a `char *`.  If the first value is equal to zero, then the system is big endian, otherwise it is little endian.

Here is an example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   uint32_t   val  = 0x01;
   char     * buff = (char *)&val;

   if (buff[0] == 0)
   {
      printf("Big endian\n");
   } else {
      printf("Little endian\n");
   };

   return(0);
}
```

I've used this method on Linux, Solaris, OS X, and FreeBSD.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this. But if `word` contains the number 40, I want that number in bytesN, not in blank or bytesA. That's why the layout is important. How uint32_t is laid out specifically.

Comment: @0A0D So you want to do this? `Status x; x.word=40; printf("%d", x.fields.bytesN);`

Comment: Your problem is that you are not reversing the order in which you access the bytes when access `Status.word`. On Big Endian ( hardware an integer is stored as B3,B2,B1,B0 however on a Little Endian an integer is stored as B0,B1,B2,B3.  This means that on on big endian hardware `((Status .fields.byteN == 15) && (Status.word == 0x0F))` whereas on little endian hardware `((Status .fields.byteN == 15) && (Status.word == 0x0F000000))`  When switching from a big endian platform rou either need to reverse the bit order of `Status.fields` or reverse the bit order used to access `Status.word`

Comment: @anatolyg you should refine your question What do you want to do if not finding out the byte order?