# Is reading an unsigned char array through an unsigned integer undefined and thus not safe?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined) question and got extremely confused on what I have to do with my code. If my reading is correct, my code below is undefined according to the current standard. Below is everything I need, and I really cannot find a better way to do this. Using left shift with OR is definitely not what I want. Is it just fine to leave it this way?

EDIT: And yes I am reading `n` after setting the values of `rbg` and not n.

```
union Pixel {
    unsigned char rgb[4];
    uint32_t n;

    Pixel():
    n(0) {}
};
```

Comment: To do what? What is your goal?

Comment: Nothing wrong this far. But if you access a member you didn't put there it is UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I want to be sure that my code does not contain undefined behaviour.

Comment: @xiver77: When? Under what conditions? You don't show how you use this `union`.

Comment: Although it is technically UB, many compilers support it as an extension, mainly because - as far as I know - this kind of type punning is allowed in C. An often suggested alternative is to use `memcpy`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952204/using-char-array-inside-union#comment22733039_15952308

Comment: @xiver77: I still see no usage code. Never mind; the above link answers your question.

Comment: do you mean  `Pixel() : n(0) {}` ?

Comment: Can you identify your reason that masking and shifting is "...definitely not what I want..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the parts of C++ where it is easier to check what your compiler is doing than following the standard. As far as I know most compilers still do what you expect (MSVC, GCC, CLANG). Are you thinking something esoteric?

In the following link the Sun C++ compiler is mentioned as not working:

http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959