# Why is output of this float union NaN?

Tags: c++, floating-point, unions

In my C++ code I have declared a union:

```
typedef union U_FloatParse {
    float float_data;
    unsigned char byte_data[4];
} U_FloatConvert;
```

Then, I set the byte_data array to the values 0, 0, 192, 127:

```
U_FloatConvert depth_data;

depth_data.byte_data[0] = 0;
depth_data.byte_data[1] = 0;
depth_data.byte_data[2] = 192;
depth_data.byte_data[3] = 127;

printf("\n\nFloat = %f\n\n", depth_data.float_data);
```

As output I get NaN. Why don't I get a normal float value? When I pass the values: 56, 137, 33, 63. I get the float value 0.631000.

Test code: http://codepad.org/Q8ds1V0F

Comment: Are you using a C compiler or a C++ one?

Comment: C or C++, tag one. `union` does not do the same thing in both.

Comment: AFAIK, this is undefined in C++. (Please tag only one of C and C++ unless you're asking about the differences between them.)

Comment: You do know the [IEEE floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)? You do know about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: NaN is expected for 0x7fc00000, nothing funny happened

Comment: What value did you expect to get?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It's either C or it's C++, but it's certainly not neither of them.

Comment: Now that you know how your system represents NaN, try 128 instead of 192 for `inf`, or `0,0,128,255` for negative infinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By writing the said bytes into the array, you get a memory layout of `00 00 c0 7f`, which, in little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), reads as `7fc00000`. Interpreting this as an [IEEE float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) gives you

- a sign of 0 (positive, but irrelevant for NaN)
- an exponent of `0xFF`
- a mantissa of 0x400000 (> 0 and has the most significant bit set → silent)

which gets you a (silent) NaN value.

At least, this counts for C. In C++, it is not defined what you do, but if you nevertheless get `NaN` as a result, your compiler treats it if it was C (not recommended nevertheless to rely on undefined behaviour!).

Answer (score 6):

NaN *is* a normal float value, and the bytes you set are correctly interpreted as [a valid NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

That being said, you could have got the output "there is no <strike>spoon</strike> NaN", since [using a union in this manner has undefined behaviour in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953675/560648). You may only use one of the union's members at any given time. It's *not* a shortcut for reinterpret-casting!

Answer (score 0):

NaN(not a number) error generally occurs if the ouput is indeterminate i.e whose value couldn't be determined such as 0/0.

But I wouldn't use unions anyway (personally don't like them), when you use a union, it is undefined behavior to set one member and extract a different member.

For one thing, floating-point values are basically split into bit fields, with so many bits holding the mantissa, so many holding the exponent, and one holding the sign. And integer, on the other hand is simply a base-2 representation of a number. Their bits just aren't arranged the same.

You could do like this:

```
unsigned long int l = byte_data[0] | (byte_data[1] << 8) | (byte_data[2] << 16) | (byte_data[3] << 24);
```

Comment: You can't build a float like that though

Comment: Ah, yes obviously... Does it have to be a float? ^^

Comment: Well maybe, I just think it's odd to answer this question with how to build an integer, that's not really what the question is about

Comment: True. Well i though the code line would just be extra, my answer was really the text i wrote. Sorry for inconvenience. What i meant was that using float, you will get 0x7fc00000 from the char array, what you really want is 0x0000c07f, which i was trying to explain.