# Type punning Vs Union member access

Tags: c, unions, type-punning

As per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812932/1814023 `writing one member of union and reading another member is undefined behavior.`

And as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640603/1814023 `type punning is allowed in C99 / C11`

I am bit confused on these two posts, which one is correct? 
Need help in understanding type punning Vs accessing the member of union.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's implementation-defined in C89:

> #### C89 3.3.2.3 Structure and union members
>
> With one exception, **if a member of a `union` object is accessed after a value has been stored in a different member of the object, the behavior is implementation-defined.** One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a `union` contains several structures that share a common initial sequence, and if the `union` object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types for a sequence of one or more initial members.

In C99/C11, it's allowed, although when it's *trap representation*, the value is indeterminate.

> #### C11 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members *footnote*
>
> If the member used to read the contents of a `union` object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

Comment: int swap_words( int arg )
{
  short int* const sp = (short int*)&arg;
  short int        hi = sp[0];
  short int        lo = sp[1];
  
  sp[1] = hi;
  sp[0] = lo;

  return (arg);
}

Comment: The above code is doing type punning and result is implementation-defined in C89?