# Binary representation with union

Tags: c, unions

In the below program:

```
union
{
  int i;
  float f;
} u;
```

Assuming 32 bit compiler, `u` is allocated with 4 bytes in memory.

```
u.f = 3.14159f;
```

`3.14159f` is represented using IEEE 754, in those 4 bytes.

```
printf("As integer: %08x\n", u.i);
```

What does `u.i` represent here? Is IEEE 754 binary representation interpreted as 4 byte `signed int`?

Comment: `u.i` represents undefined behavior.

Comment: "`u` is allocated with 4 bytes in memory" - not guaranteed, depends on the compiler

Comment: That edit is still not correct - the standard does not define what size `int` or `float` have (only a minimum size) - it's up to the compiler vendor what sizes they actually use in their implementation

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes I read that from K&R, in  college

Comment: @tkausl `u.i` is not undefined behaviour. But using `%x` to print a negativ `int` is undefined.

Comment: @overexchange use `unsigned int i` or `uint32_t i`

Comment: @M.M do you mean, IEEE 754 binary represenation is read as 4 byte `signed int`?

Comment: no, I mean that your `i` is a signed int, so you cannot use `%x` to print it

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is exactly. `u.i` is an `int` whose bytes are the same as the bytes of `u.f`  , what do you mean by "represent" ?

Answer (score 3):

Reading from `i` is *implementation-defined* blah blah blah.

Still.

On "normal" platforms where

- `float` is [IEEE-754 binary32 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)
- `int` is 32 bit 2's complement
- the endianness of `float` and `int` [is the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point)
- type punning through `union`s [is well defined (C99+)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union)

(AKA any "regular" PC with a recent enough compiler)

you will get the integer whose bit pattern matches the one of your original `float`, which is described [e.g. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)

[image: float bit pattern]

Now, there's the sign bit that messes up stuff with the 2's complement representation of `int`, so you probably want to use an `unsigned` type to do this kind of experimentation. Also, `memcpy` is a safer way to perform type-punning (you won't get dirty looks and discussions about the standard), so if you do something like:

```
float x = 1234.5678;
uint32_t x_u;
memcpy(&x_u, &x, sizeof x_u);
```

Now you can easily extract the various parts of the FP representation:

```
int sign     = x_u>>31;                    // 0 = positive; 1 = negative
int exponent = ((x_u>>23) & 0xff;          // apply -127 bias to obtain actual exponent
int mantissa = x_u & ~((unsigned(-1)<<23);
```

(notice that this ignores completely all the "magic" patterns - quiet and signaling NaNs and subnormal numbers come to mind)

Comment: Suggest `memcpy(&x_u, &x, sizeof x_u);`.  No need for casts.  Avoid magic numbers.

Comment: @chux: casts: yep, I originally wrote them for `char *`, then I remembered that `memcpy` takes `void *`, but I didn't remove them; for 4, it's not really magic - we are talking about and `uint32_t` and a `float` in the very specific case where they are *required* to be 4, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812359), reading from any element of the union other than the last one written is either undefined behavior or implementation defined behavior depending on the version of the standard.

If you want to examine the binary representation of `3.14159f`, you can do so by casting the address of a `float` and then dereferencing.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    float f = 3.14159f;
    printf("%x\n", *(uint32_t*) &f);
}
```

The output of this program is `40490fd0`, which matches with the result given by [this page](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

As interjay correctly pointed out, the technique I present above violates the strict aliasing rule. To make the above code work correctly, one must pass the flag `-fno-strict-aliasing` to `gcc` or the equivalent flag to disable optimizations based on strict aliasing on other compilers.

---

Another way of viewing the bytes which does not violate strict aliasing and does not require the flag is using a `char *` instead.

```
unsigned char* cp = (unsigned char*) &f;
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x\n",cp[0],cp[1],cp[2],cp[3]);
```

Note that on little endian architectures such as x86, this will produce bytes in the opposite order as the first suggestion.

Comment: This is a violation of the strict aliasing rule, and thus undefined.

Comment: @interjay, That is correct. I will amend the answer.

Comment: This is a C question, you linked to a C++ answer

Comment: The new linked answer is wrong (it says this is undefined behaviour but in fact it isn't).

Comment: I would swap the two halves of the question, type punning through straight pointer cast is the "most UB way" to do type punning. While virtually all compilers have well defined behavior for type punning through `union`s, strict aliasing is exploited quite liberally unless you explicitly ask for it to be well defined.

Comment: @m.m the comment underneath it is correct and I've excerpted from both.